# Backbone.js 'add' and 'sync' events are redundant

Tags: backbone.js

I have a SPA app that's a blogging app of sorts. You post, and then the 'feed' composite view puts the post on top.

What I envision: 
1. have a `sync` `listenTo` on the post collection that, on the collection `fetch()`, loads all the posts.
2. have an `add` `listenTo` on the collection that will render a new post when it's added.

The problem is that on `fetch()`, I'm getting both `add` and `sync` events which causes duplicate posts.

What do you all suggest I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fetch()` for the first time on an empty collection, the collection will fire an `add` event for all new models, so listening for that should be enough.

When you call `fetch()` when the collection already has models, you will only get an `add` event for new models.